# Doit-on employer le subjonctif après « il faut que » ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Comment dit-on en français : « il faut que tu soit du retour » ou « il faut que tu es du retour » ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A vrai dire, ni l'un ni l'autre. La phrase correcte est :

> Il faut que tu *sois de* retour.

Avec *sois* plutôt que *soit*, *de* plutôt que *du*.

Comment: Merçi de corriger mon erreur.

Comment: @LucianSava **Merci**, sans cédille. La cédille s’utilise devant les voyelles “a” “o” et “u” quand il faut prononcer le “c” [s] plutôt que [k].

Answer (score 0):

Oui, toujours le subjonctif dans ce cas puisque l'action est incertaine.